# How to deal with a dynamic input sizes in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Placeholder declared this way:

```
self._sentence_lengths = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=[None], name='sen_len')
```

I also have an `embeds` tensor whose shape is `(?, 300)`.

I would like to perform a split of the `embeds` based on the `sentence_lengths` : `sentences = tf.split(embeds, self._sentence_lengths)`

however, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot infer num from shape Tensor("joint_architecture_1/encoder_1/sen_len:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32)
```

Initially, I was creating `self._sentence_lengths` this way (everything worked fine):

`self._sentence_lengths = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=[self.batch_size], name='sen_len')`

The reason I wanted to change it to a dynamic approach is that I do not want to be limited by a batch size. Indeed, when training one might use a batch size of, say, 128. But when doing inference, I need small batch sizes.

The way I have been doing it so far is that I am changing the `self.batch_size` when restoring but that does not seem to be elegant.

Would there be a way to overcome this issue?

Comment: You can have dynamic size of tensor, but not dynamic number of tensors. Having dynamic number of tensors means the graph structure depends on the output of run call, however graph structure must be independent of the data that's fed through. So you have to design your dynamic computation without using split (perhaps dynamic_partition, and fixed number of output tensors, some of them empty)

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of using a fixed-size variable that would be big enough for the my placeholder's size. Do the computations then truncate the useless part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to this problem using a small trick. I created a constant Tensor that  will hold the contents of my Variable. That Tensor's size will limit the size of sen_len but if we choose it big enough, that should not be an issue.

Here is a toy example of my solution>

```
    embeds_raw = tf.constant(np.array([
    [1, 1],
    [1, 1],
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
    [3, 3],
    [3, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [4, 4],
    [4, 4],
    [4, 4],
], dtype='float32'))
# These play the role of embeddings.
embeds = tf.Variable(initial_value=embeds_raw)
# This variable plays the role of a container. We chose zeros because they are neutral to addition.
container_variable = tf.zeros([512], dtype=tf.int32, name='container_variable')
# Our placeholder for sentence lengths.
sen_len = tf.placeholder('int32', shape=[None], name='sen_len')
# Getting the length of the longest sentence.
max_l = tf.reduce_max(sen_len)
# Number of sentences.
nbr_sentences = tf.shape(sen_len)[0]
# We pad the sentence length var to match that of the container variable.
padded_sen_len = tf.pad(sen_len, [[0, 512 - nbr_sentences]], 'CONSTANT')
# We add the sentence lengths to our container variable.
added_container_variable = tf.add(container_variable, padded_sen_len)
# Create a TensorArray that will contain the split.
u1 = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=512, clear_after_read=False)
# Split the embeddings by the sentence lengths.
u1 = u1.split(embeds, added_container_variable)

# Loop variables. An index and a variable containing our concatenated arrays.
i = tf.constant(0, shape=(), dtype='int32', name='i')
x = tf.constant(0, shape=[1, 2], dtype=tf.float32)

def condition(_i, _):
    """Checking whether _i is less than the number of sentences."""
    return tf.less(_i, nbr_sentences)

def body(_i, _x):
    """Padding and concatenating with _x."""
    temp = tf.pad(u1.read(_i), [[0, max_l - sen_len[_i]], [0, 0]], 'CONSTANT')
    return _i + 1, tf.concat([_x, temp], 0)

# Looping.
idx, padded_concatenated_sentences = tf.while_loop(
    condition,
    body,
    [i, x],
    shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([None, 2])]
)

# Getting rid of the first row since it contains 0s.
padded_concatenated_sentences = padded_concatenated_sentences[1:]

# Reshaping to obtain the desired results. In our case 2 would be the word embedding dimensionality.
reshaped_elements = tf.reshape(padded_concatenated_sentences, [nbr_sentences, max_l, 2])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sents = sess.run(reshaped_elements, feed_dict={sen_len: [2, 1, 3, 4]})
    print(sents)
```